# Sibling floating divs extend same vertical distance

Tags: html, css, css-float

I don't think I'm a total dunce when it comes to CSS but this one has me.  The idea is I need a parent element with two floating children to either side.  I want the parent height to extend as tall as the children are, and have the children height become equal depending on which child is taller.  I have it close but it is not quite there yet.  I made this plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/kz9VyOxMCLahPbNmyt87?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to set both elements to `display:table-cell`, which will basically force them to have the same height as their containing contents.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eg5UzERypUTNSL4msiX8?p=preview)

```
.left, .right {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

This would also require you to remove the floats on the elements.

Comment: Obviously your example is working, but adding that to my original code DOES NOT work.  It doesn't make any sense.  **UPDATE** I notice you removed the floating left right from the .left and .right.  Any way to get it to work without doing so?

Comment: Seeing as how I can't find a real reason not to, I will mark this correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @ErikDonohoo Is there a reason they **need** to be floating elements? If this is because you can't modify the original coding, just overwrite it with `float:none`.